# App language fallbacks to default if English has higher priority in Android

Tags: android, internationalization

The default language of my app is Chinese. I have string resources put in folders:

- `values` (default, Chinese)
- `values-ja-rJP` (Japanese)

If my system language list is set to:

1. Spanish
2. Japanese
3. English

My app displays in Japanese, which is the expected behavior. My app does not support Spanish, so falling back to Japanese.

But if I change the system language list to:

1. English
2. Japanese
3. Spanish

My app now displays in the default language, which is Chinese in my case. I wonder why it doesn't fallback to Japanese?

As for the difference between English and Spanish (and others), does Android excpect apps to provide English as the default language?